# SQL modules in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating a C# application which will have to upload and read data from a SQL database. In school I learned the raw database calls but I am wondering if there is a free tool which lets me work easier and faster with the database call.

I also need to be sure that none is editing on the same line in the table at the same time so it could be nice if the tool also had something to ensure this.

Hope some of you have some great experiences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Object Relational Mappers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

The favourites at this time a [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) and [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723), but there are [many others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET).

Comment: does they ensure all my needs?

Comment: I use EF, it's quick and efficient. It certainly meets all your needs as far as easier and faster.